# Get the index number of a certain architecture in a Windows Image

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, dism

I have an Windows 7 image (WIM) that contains multiple architectures. I want to know the index number of an particular architecture, inside the image.

For example, the image contains (In no specific order):

- Windows 7 Ultimate x64
- Windows 7 Ultimate x86
- Windows 7 Professional x64
- Windows 7 Professional x86
- Windows 7 Home Premium x64
- Windows 7 Home Premium x86

I do not have the index number of **any** of the above versions.

I want to retrieve the index number of Windows 7 Professional x64 in my windows image file. How would I go about this:

So far, I've came up with:

```
if exist %TEMP%\scm (RD %TEMP%\scm /S /Q)
md %TEMP%\scm

for /L %%A IN (1, 1, 12) Do (

dism /Get-WimInfo /WimFile:h:\research\Win7x64\InstallWin7_aio\sources\install.wim /index:%%A > %TEMP%\scm\%%A.txt
Findstr "Windows 7 Ultimate" %Temp%\scm\%%A.TXT && Findstr "x64" %Temp%\scm\%%A.TXT > nul
IF %ERRORLEVEL% == 0 (ECHO "It is Windows 7 Ultimate x64")

)

pause
```

I'm getting the below output

```
H:\>for /L %A IN (1 1 12) Do (
dism /Get-WimInfo /WimFile:h:\research\Win7x64\InstallWin7_aio\sources\install.wim /index:%A  1>C:\Users\Tarak\AppData\Local\Temp\scm\%A.txt
Findstr "Windows 7 Ultimate" C:\Users\Tarak\AppData\Local\Temp\scm\%A.TXT   && Findstr "x64" C:\Users\Tarak\AppData\Local\Temp\scm\%A.TXT  1>nul
IF 0 == 0 (ECHO "It is Windows 7 Ultimate x64" )
ECHO 0
)

H:\>(
dism /Get-WimInfo /WimFile:h:\research\Win7x64\InstallWin7_aio\sources\install.wim /index:1  1>C:\Users\Tarak\AppData\Local\Temp\scm\1.txt
Findstr "Windows 7 Ultimate" C:\Users\Tarak\AppData\Local\Temp\scm\1.TXT   && Findstr "x64" C:\Users\Tarak\AppData\Local\Temp\scm\1.TXT  1>nul
IF 0 == 0 (ECHO "It is Windows 7 Ultimate x64" )
ECHO 0
)
Details for image : h:\research\Win7x64\InstallWin7_aio\sources\install.wim
Name : Windows 7 Starter
Description : Windows 7 Starter
Size : 8,072,604,598 bytes
Version : 6.1.7601
ServicePack Build : 17514
Files : 46887
"It is Windows 7 Ultimate x64"
0

H:\>(
dism /Get-WimInfo /WimFile:h:\research\Win7x64\InstallWin7_aio\sources\install.wim /index:2  1>C:\Users\Tarak\AppData\Local\Temp\scm\2.txt
Findstr "Windows 7 Ultimate" C:\Users\Tarak\AppData\Local\Temp\scm\2.TXT   && Findstr "x64" C:\Users\Tarak\AppData\Local\Temp\scm\2.TXT  1>nul
IF 0 == 0 (ECHO "It is Windows 7 Ultimate x64" )
ECHO 0
)
Details for image : h:\research\Win7x64\InstallWin7_aio\sources\install.wim
Name : Windows 7 Home Basic
Description : Windows 7 Home Basic
Size : 8,125,226,573 bytes
Version : 6.1.7601
ServicePack Build : 17514
Files : 47090
"It is Windows 7 Ultimate x64"
0

H:\>(
dism /Get-WimInfo /WimFile:h:\research\Win7x64\InstallWin7_aio\sources\install.wim /index:3  1>C:\Users\Tarak\AppData\Local\Temp\scm\3.txt
Findstr "Windows 7 Ultimate" C:\Users\Tarak\AppData\Local\Temp\scm\3.TXT   && Findstr "x64" C:\Users\Tarak\AppData\Local\Temp\scm\3.TXT  1>nul
IF 0 == 0 (ECHO "It is Windows 7 Ultimate x64" )
ECHO 0
)
Details for image : h:\research\Win7x64\InstallWin7_aio\sources\install.wim
Name : Windows 7 Home Premium
Description : Windows 7 Home Premium
Version : 6.1.7601
ServicePack Build : 17514
"It is Windows 7 Ultimate x64"
0

H:\>(
dism /Get-WimInfo /WimFile:h:\research\Win7x64\InstallWin7_aio\sources\install.wim /index:4  1>C:\Users\Tarak\AppData\Local\Temp\scm\4.txt
Findstr "Windows 7 Ultimate" C:\Users\Tarak\AppData\Local\Temp\scm\4.TXT   && Findstr "x64" C:\Users\Tarak\AppData\Local\Temp\scm\4.TXT  1>nul
IF 0 == 0 (ECHO "It is Windows 7 Ultimate x64" )
ECHO 0
)
Details for image : h:\research\Win7x64\InstallWin7_aio\sources\install.wim
Name : Windows 7 Professional
Description : Windows 7 Professional
Size : 8,447,825,392 bytes
Version : 6.1.7601
ServicePack Build : 17514
"It is Windows 7 Ultimate x64"
0

H:\>(
dism /Get-WimInfo /WimFile:h:\research\Win7x64\InstallWin7_aio\sources\install.wim /index:5  1>C:\Users\Tarak\AppData\Local\Temp\scm\5.txt
Findstr "Windows 7 Ultimate" C:\Users\Tarak\AppData\Local\Temp\scm\5.TXT   && Findstr "x64" C:\Users\Tarak\AppData\Local\Temp\scm\5.TXT  1>nul
IF 0 == 0 (ECHO "It is Windows 7 Ultimate x64" )
ECHO 0
)
Details for image : h:\research\Win7x64\InstallWin7_aio\sources\install.wim
Name : Windows 7 Ultimate
Description : Windows 7 Ultimate
Size : 8,607,765,255 bytes
Version : 6.1.7601
ServicePack Build : 17514
Edition : Ultimate
Files : 48718
"It is Windows 7 Ultimate x64"
0

H:\>(
dism /Get-WimInfo     /WimFile:h:\research\Win7x64\InstallWin7_aio\sources\install.wim /index:6 1>C:\Users\Tarak\AppData\Local\Temp\scm\6.txt
Findstr "Windows 7 Ultimate" C:\Users\Tarak\AppData\Local\Temp\scm\6.TXT   && Findstr "x64" C:\Users\Tarak\AppData\Local\Temp\scm\6.TXT  1>nul
IF 0 == 0 (ECHO "It is Windows 7 Ultimate x64" )
ECHO 0
)
Details for image : h:\research\Win7x64\InstallWin7_aio\sources\install.wim
Name : Windows 7 Home Basic
Description : Windows 7 Home Basic
Size : 11,707,704,502 bytes
Version : 6.1.7601
ServicePack Build : 17514
Files : 64267
"It is Windows 7 Ultimate x64"
0

H:\>(
dism /Get-WimInfo /WimFile:h:\research\Win7x64\InstallWin7_aio\sources\install.wim /index:7  1>C:\Users\Tarak\AppData\Local\Temp\scm\7.txt
Findstr "Windows 7 Ultimate" C:\Users\Tarak\AppData\Local\Temp\scm\7.TXT   && Findstr "x64" C:\Users\Tarak\AppData\Local\Temp\scm\7.TXT  1>nul
IF 0 == 0 (ECHO "It is Windows 7 Ultimate x64" )
ECHO 0
)
Details for image : h:\research\Win7x64\InstallWin7_aio\sources\install.wim
Index : 7
Name : Windows 7 Home Premium
Description : Windows 7 Home Premium
Version : 6.1.7601
ServicePack Build : 17514
Modified : 21-Apr-11 - 06:07:36
"It is Windows 7 Ultimate x64"
0

H:\>(
dism /Get-WimInfo /WimFile:h:\research\Win7x64\InstallWin7_aio\sources\install.wim /index:8  1>C:\Users\Tarak\AppData\Local\Temp\scm\8.txt
Findstr "Windows 7 Ultimate" C:\Users\Tarak\AppData\Local\Temp\scm\8.TXT   && Findstr "x64" C:\Users\Tarak\AppData\Local\Temp\scm\8.TXT  1>nul
IF 0 == 0 (ECHO "It is Windows 7 Ultimate x64" )
ECHO 0
)
Details for image : h:\research\Win7x64\InstallWin7_aio\sources\install.wim
Name : Windows 7 Professional
Description : Windows 7 Professional
Version : 6.1.7601
ServicePack Build : 17514
"It is Windows 7 Ultimate x64"
0

H:\>(
dism /Get-WimInfo /WimFile:h:\research\Win7x64\InstallWin7_aio\sources\install.wim /index:9  1>C:\Users\Tarak\AppData\Local\Temp\scm\9.txt
Findstr "Windows 7 Ultimate" C:\Users\Tarak\AppData\Local\Temp\scm\9.TXT   && Findstr "x64" C:\Users\Tarak\AppData\Local\Temp\scm\9.TXT  1>nul
IF 0 == 0 (ECHO "It is Windows 7 Ultimate x64" )
ECHO 0
)
Details for image : h:\research\Win7x64\InstallWin7_aio\sources\install.wim
Name : Windows 7 Ultimate
Description : Windows 7 Ultimate
Version : 6.1.7601
ServicePack Build : 17514
Edition : Ultimate
Directories : 13735
"It is Windows 7 Ultimate x64"
0

H:\>(
dism /Get-WimInfo    /WimFile:h:\research\Win7x64\InstallWin7_aio\sources\install.wim /index:10  1>C:\Users\Tarak\AppData\Local\Temp\scm\10.txt
Findstr "Windows 7 Ultimate" C:\Users\Tarak\AppData\Local\Temp\scm\10.TXT   && Findstr "x64" C:\Users\Tarak\AppData\Local\Temp\scm\10.TXT  1>nul
IF 0 == 0 (ECHO "It is Windows 7 Ultimate x64" )
ECHO 0
)
Error: 87
"It is Windows 7 Ultimate x64"
0

H:\>(
dism /Get-WimInfo /WimFile:h:\research\Win7x64\InstallWin7_aio\sources\install.wim /index:11  1>C:\Users\Tarak\AppData\Local\Temp\scm\11.txt
Findstr "Windows 7 Ultimate" C:\Users\Tarak\AppData\Local\Temp\scm\11.TXT   && Findstr "x64" C:\Users\Tarak\AppData\Local\Temp\scm\11.TXT  1>nul
IF 0 == 0 (ECHO "It is Windows 7 Ultimate x64" )
ECHO 0
)  
Error: 87
"It is Windows 7 Ultimate x64"
0

H:\>(
dism /Get-WimInfo /WimFile:h:\research\Win7x64\InstallWin7_aio\sources\install.wim /index:12  1>C:\Users\Tarak\AppData\Local\Temp\scm\12.txt
Findstr "Windows 7 Ultimate" C:\Users\Tarak\AppData\Local\Temp\scm\12.TXT   && Findstr "x64" C:\Users\Tarak\AppData\Local\Temp\scm\12.TXT  1>nul
IF 0 == 0 (ECHO "It is Windows 7 Ultimate x64" )
ECHO 0
)
Error: 87
"It is Windows 7 Ultimate x64"
0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enable the `delayed expansion`if you want to test directly the `!errorlevel!` and you'll better use the `/i` switch with `findstr`:

Or use directly `&&` :

```
@echo off

if exist %TEMP%\scm (RD %TEMP%\scm /S /Q)
md %TEMP%\scm

for /L %%A IN (1, 1, 12) Do (

dism /Get-WimInfo /WimFile:h:\research\Win7x64\InstallWin7_aio\sources\install.wim /index:%%A > %TEMP%\scm\%%A.txt
Find /i "Windows 7 Ultimate" "%Temp%\scm\%%A.TXT" && Find /i "Architecture : x64" "%Temp%\scm\%%A.TXT" && (
      set "Index=%%A"
      goto:next
) 
)

exit/b

:next
ECHO "Windows 7 Ultimate x64" is in Index : %Index%
```

Comment: Sorry buddy this dose not work, because it shows the Windows 7 Ultimate x64 image is in index 1 while it is actually in index 9. I sense that the errorlevel causing the problem. But, do not know how to solve it

Comment: Ok check my Edit without testing the errorlevel directly.

Comment: Still same result

Comment: Try again i corrected %%a with %%A, Do you have a file named 9.txt with the string "Windows 7 Ultimate and the string "x64" in it

Comment: I have already corrected %%A and then replied here. And if you read the code carefully i am using 'For' loop with (1, 1, 12) parameters, this will continue loop till 12.txt is created and meanwhile if our code finds its string in 9.txt i has to get out of the loop.

Comment: Yes I know what is ta FOR /L loop. but I don't see the string "x64" in your example. Thats what I'm asking. Just control the file 9.txt

Comment: Findstr /i "Windows 7 Ultimate" %Temp%\scm\%%A.TXT && Findstr /i "x64" %Temp%\scm\%%A.TXT > nul                                            i am trying to find two strings in a single file

Comment: I NOW that Man, BUT Did you check if the file 9.txt contain the string "x64" ?????

Comment: It will be created itself in for loop.

Comment: Again check if the file 9.txt contain the string "x64"

Comment: What can be the cause of errorlevel remain 0 even if finds an error ? It is happening in our code. Thats why the code dosent go beyond %%A = 1 in For loop

Comment: if i run the command dism with /index:9, it shows me Architecture : x64 and also Name : Windows 7 Ultimate

Comment: Did you try to put a tempo between the `dism` command and the first `findstr` ? Check my Edit again with `timeout`

Comment: Hmm. But, same result. Still we need to check out the errorlevel or we wont be able to get the correct index no.

Comment: The errorlevel value does not change even if the loop goes from %%A = 1 to %%A = 12. It has to be 0 only on %%A = 9 and 1 on others.

Comment: Ok ! just one thing if you directly test the `errorlevel` and you have a composed name in your path then you'll get an errorlevel of 2 (with findstr) . I putted `"` between the path and used `find` in place of `findstr`. Try again my LAST EDIT

Comment: Still no success as the errorlevel on %%A is 0, while it has to be 1 or something else.

Comment: Ok it found on 5the index but it still dosent find x64 because 5th index is of Windows 7 Ultimate x86

Comment: Without the output file is difficult to find the problem

Comment: ---------- C:\USERS\TARAK\APPDATA\LOCAL\TEMP\SCM\1.TXT

---------- C:\USERS\TARAK\APPDATA\LOCAL\TEMP\SCM\2.TXT

---------- C:\USERS\TARAK\APPDATA\LOCAL\TEMP\SCM\3.TXT

---------- C:\USERS\TARAK\APPDATA\LOCAL\TEMP\SCM\4.TXT

---------- C:\USERS\TARAK\APPDATA\LOCAL\TEMP\SCM\5.TXT
Name : Windows 7 Ultimate
Description : Windows 7 Ultimate

Comment: I mean the content of 9.txt

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124159/discussion-between-tarak-bhavsar-and-sachadee).

Answer (score 0):

Easy. Just use `find` and output the line number with `/n`, then use either a math calculation (more robust but potentially few milliseconds slower because code have more lines, untested), or either use a double find.

**Solution 1:**

```
for /f "tokens=1 delims=[]" %%i in ('"dism /get-wiminfo /wimfile:"d:\wims\Windows7Wim\sources\install.wim" | find /n /i "Name" | find /i /n "Windows 7 Professional x64""') do set "my_windows_wim_index=%%i"
```

You start by displaying the line number in front of each "Name" in the output, for example it will show line "[22]".

```
[3]Windows 7 Ultimate x64
[9]Windows 7 Ultimate x86
[13]Windows 7 Professional x64
[15]Windows 7 Professional x86
[19]Windows 7 Home Premium x64
[22]Windows 7 Home Premium x86
```

This is the first pipe in find. Now, you pipe a second time, it will show only the Windows names, but with the "pseudo-index" infront :

```
[1][3]Windows 7 Ultimate x64
[2][9]Windows 7 Ultimate x86
[3][13]Windows 7 Professional x64
[4][15]Windows 7 Professional x86
[5][19]Windows 7 Home Premium x64
[6][22]Windows 7 Home Premium x86
```

Because you used a for loop, you can extract the number 4. As you see, this is solely based on the assumption that dism will always show the index in ascending order from `1` to `n`.

**Solution 2:**

```
for /f "tokens=1 delims=[]" %i in ('"dism /get-wiminfo /wimfile:"d:\wims\Windows7Wim\sources\install.wim" | find /n "Nom" | find /i "Windows 7 Professional x64""') do (set "goodnumber=%i")
set /a "goodnumber-=1"
for /f "tokens=2 delims= " %i in ('"dism /get-wiminfo /wimfile:"d:\wims\Windows7Wim\sources\install.wim" | find /n "Index" | find /i "[%goodnumber%]""') do (echo "my_windows_wim_index=%i")
```

Its the same idea, but it will directly extract the line number, do a calculation, and query again the dism to extract the index. Could be few milliseconds slower but more robust.